# Reduce the main form code by deferring it other classes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My program has only one form. But that one form is going to have more than 6 panels each containing some tabs. If I put all this logic within one form the code becomes bulky.

What is the best way to at least handle each panel's work in a different place?

Comment: Create custom controls.

Comment: Gee @Tony, you should make that comment an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build up your form with controls, for example you can create a control per tab page.

A control is basically a UI widget. You create it once and it is then a self-contained unit, reusable and "abstract" in the sense that the form itself does not have access to the control's internals, only to those properties and methods you make public.

A control can also be made out of other controls (this is then a "composite control"). This way, you can create very complex UI's easily by composing controls out of existing and custom controls.

Here are a few links to get you going:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6hws6h2t(v=vs.100).aspx
- http://techymedia.com/post/2013/04/21/How-to-create-custom-Control-In-C-Sharp-Tutorial-Step-By-Step.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4871/Divider-Panel-A-tutorial-on-creating-a-custom-Wind

Comment: This sounds very reasonable and nice @Roy. But then each separate user control will have its own DLL file. That means I should first completely and separately develop each user control. My panels are in fact subject to change all the time and their state affect each other. Do you still think I should go on with that?

Comment: No, it's not necessary to have a separate DLL per control. You can put all your controls in a single DLL or even in the same project as your form.

Comment: DLL apart, should I create a separate User Control for each tab of my form? And then place all the controls I want in that user control so my main form's task would only be to display that control whenever I demand it, too? You can give me a strict answer, I don't mind and I'll be grateful.

Comment: That is what I would do! One custom control on each tab. Of course, each custom control can, itself, also be composed of other custom controls. Use your judgment to see what makes sense to you.

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote in comments, create custom controls. There are many articles dedicated to this:

- [Writing your Custom Control: step by step](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2016/Writing-your-Custom-Control-step-by-step)
- [Creating a Windows Form User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)

  And so on..

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dll for that programm add this dll in another projects and use this..

or

you have to create custom control for that it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Create a `User Control` and then add it to the tab page. To create a user control r-click on the project then `Add` then `User Control`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split application logic into multiple classes then create User controls.
If you just want to split your source code into multiple files then use Partial Classes.